# react-native-pdf Expo build failure

Tags: react-native, npm, build, expo

trying to install `react-native-pdf` . i created a new a build and got an `eas.json` file but the i then get the following error

```
`Failed to resolve plugin for module "Failed to resolve plugin for module "@config-plugins/react-native-blob-util" relative to "PROJECT DIRECTORY ADDRESS"
    Error: build command failed.
```

I have copy and pasted the following plugin into my `app.json` as well as installed botht the `react-native-pdf` and `blob` packages:

```
"plugins": [
      "@config-plugins/react-native-blob-util",
      "@config-plugins/react-native-pdf"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

first delete the node modules and have the cache cleared on expo.
rm -rf node_modules.
yarn install
expo start -c
now that you have cleared the cache stop the server.
do
yarn add react-native-pdf react-native-blob-util @config-plugins/react-native-pdf @config-plugins/react-native-blob-util
in the app.json file add the plugins under expo.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      "@config-plugins/react-native-blob-util",
      "@config-plugins/react-native-pdf"
    ]
  }
}
```

now assuming you dont have the eas.json file generated as the build failed. you can do:-    eas build:configure
and follow the steps
Now that the eas.json file is generated,
under the build inside the development add the simulator to be true something like this

```
"ios": {
    "simulator": true
  }
```

this is to run it on the simulator.